# Variational method for finding largest eigenvalue and eigenvector of a completely positive map

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking to find approximations of the largest eigenvalue and the left and right eigenvectors of a completely positive map. I have the following eigenvalue problem:
$$ \phi \rho = \lambda \rho$$
where $\phi$ is a completely positive linear map acting on a complex $N\times N$ matrix $\rho$. The map $\phi$ is not self-adjoint.
I thought about trying to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\max_{\sigma,\rho}\{Tr(\sigma \phi \rho) \,|\,  \sigma,\rho \in \text{Hermitian matrices}\} $$
where $\sigma$ and $\rho$ are the left and right eigenoperators that I am trying to find, subject also to the normalization $Tr(\rho)=1$ and $Tr(\sigma \rho)=1$.

However, I believe this does not work because $\phi$ is not self-adjoint. Is there something else that can be done?